# Upper bound of $S=\sum_{k=1}^{P}k!\binom{P}{k}\binom{Q}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinations

EDIT: How can I find a good upper bound to this quantity ?

$$S_{n,m}=\sum_{k=1}^{P}k!\binom{P}{k}\binom{Q}{k}$$

where $P=\min\{m,n\}$ et $Q=\max\{m,n\}$.

Comment: Well, by a counting argument, it is the number of bijections between non-empty subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,m\}$ and $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$. Might be easier to count that, might not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how this upper bound is good but this is one that you can use.

So here is the hint: In this paper, [Asymptotic Enumeration Methods (1995)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.53.9953), there is an upper bound as follow (which can be found [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas) too):

$$\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)^k \le {n \choose k}  \le \frac{n^k}{k!} \le \left(\frac{n\cdot e}{k}\right)^k,\; \text{for}\; 1\leqslant k\leqslant n.$$

Now, suppose that $M>N$ and find the upper bound. Do the same for $N>M$.